# Logon Failed in Crstal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

We are getting error when we open Crystal Report from my asp.net application at test server. We are using credentials in web.config. I have supplied userid, password, server and database name in web.config. Here is the error:

```
Logon failed.
Details: ADO Error Code: 0x
Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
Description: Login failed for user 'username'.
SQL State: 42000
Native Error: 
Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\temp_52ca33ea-cdc8-4e76-ae02-d208d8dce6c6 {D554C65C-94E7-4477-85BD-62C73E4F0258}.rpt:
Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.
```

We are using SQL server 2014.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to log into the same SQL instance through SSMS with the same user and password?

Comment: You are going to need to show some code here.

Comment: @JacobH, yes, I can login through SSMS and also in .net app with same suer, but when I click on button that uses the crystal report and generate the report at that point it throw this error.

Comment: @Chuck, I wish i could show the code here but I'm sorry :(

Comment: Have you tried setting the login info for each table individually? Have you verified that login information from web.config reaches your report correctly?

Comment: @dd4711, yes I've tried that and yes my logon info does reach to report correctly.

Comment: have you mention Provider name in your web.config?